# Check that a PHP questionnaire was filled just once by a visitor

Tags: php

I am conceiving a PHP application that allows questionnaires deployment for polls.
I have to set programmatically this constraint:
A visitor can only fill the questionnaire one time.
I have thought of some ideas like cookies and IP addresses.
Do you have some other interesting technics?

Comment: IP addresses are bad because multiple people sharing the same internet (office, home, school) typically all share the same IP. Cookies can be easily cleared. The only way to make sure is to require an account. However there would still be nothing stopping someone from just creating multiple accounts. Creating an account is just typically more work than it is worth for increasing the vote on a poll.

Comment: Plenty of questions on this site on how to prevent "vote stuffing". A survey is just a non-election vote.